# Finding the formula for the sequence $\sqrt[3]{4} ,\sqrt[3]{4\cdot\sqrt[3]{4}},\sqrt[3]{4\cdot\sqrt[3]{4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}}} , \cdots $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't seem to figure out how to find an algebraic formula for the following sequence of numbers.

> $$\sqrt[3]{4} ,\sqrt[3]{4\cdot\sqrt[3]{4}},\sqrt[3]{4\cdot\sqrt[3]{4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}}} , \sqrt[3]{4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4\cdot \sqrt[3]{4}}}} , \cdots$$

Can somebody help?

Comment: Do you know how to convert that to exponential notation? That always help me in problems of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that if $a_n$ is the $n$-th member of this sequence, with $a_0 = 1$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
a_{n+1} 
&=& (4a_n)^{1/3} \\
&=&  4^{1/3}a_n^{1/3} \\
&=&  4^{1/3}4^{1/9}a_{n-1}^{1/9} \\
&\vdots& \\
&=&  4^{1/3 + 1/9 + \ldots + 1/3^{n+1}}a_0^{1/3^n}\\
&=& 4^{1/3 + 1/9 + \ldots + 1/3^{n+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
and now we just need to compute the geometric series in the exponent :)